# How to display wave graph like ECG or pulse graph in iPad?

Tags: ipad, graph, core-plot, wave, pulse

I want to display wave graph like ECG graph or pulse graph.if any one know,please give the solution or sample code.

Comment: Apple has sample code that does exactly that. Checkout Audio Unit, Core Audio or AV Foundation. I can't remember which one exactly but you should be able to find it...

Answer (score 0):

It is more a math (numerical analysis) question than an `iPad` specific one.

Why do you want to display it? If it is only for visual purposes you might just display images of a "real" ECG ...

I would try a linear combination of trigonometric functions with random coefficients, something like a sum of (e.g. half a dozen) terms of the form `a*sin(b*x+c)` with `a`, `b`, `c` being random constants (different for each term). But I may be wrong.

Perhaps learning more about [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) should be relevant